# What can I do to run callbacks in parallel using plotly dash?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python, waitress

I have a dashboard built on plotly dash. It is very similar to this dashboard--

```
import datetime

import dash
from dash import dcc, html
import plotly
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

# pip install pyorbital
from pyorbital.orbital import Orbital
satellite = Orbital('TERRA')

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div(
    html.Div([
        html.H4('TERRA Satellite Live Feed'),
        html.Div(id='live-update-text'),
        dcc.Graph(id='live-update-graph'),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='interval-component',
            interval=1*1000, # in milliseconds
            n_intervals=0
        )
    ])
)


@app.callback(Output('live-update-text', 'children'),
              Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'))
def update_metrics(n):
    lon, lat, alt = satellite.get_lonlatalt(datetime.datetime.now())
    style = {'padding': '5px', 'fontSize': '16px'}
    return [
        html.Span('Longitude: {0:.2f}'.format(lon), style=style),
        html.Span('Latitude: {0:.2f}'.format(lat), style=style),
        html.Span('Altitude: {0:0.2f}'.format(alt), style=style)
    ]


# Multiple components can update everytime interval gets fired.
@app.callback(Output('live-update-graph', 'figure'),
              Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'))
def update_graph_live(n):
    satellite = Orbital('TERRA')
    data = {
        'time': [],
        'Latitude': [],
        'Longitude': [],
        'Altitude': []
    }

    # Collect some data
    for i in range(180):
        time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=i*20)
        lon, lat, alt = satellite.get_lonlatalt(
            time
        )
        data['Longitude'].append(lon)
        data['Latitude'].append(lat)
        data['Altitude'].append(alt)
        data['time'].append(time)

    # Create the graph with subplots
    fig = plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, vertical_spacing=0.2)
    fig['layout']['margin'] = {
        'l': 30, 'r': 10, 'b': 30, 't': 10
    }
    fig['layout']['legend'] = {'x': 0, 'y': 1, 'xanchor': 'left'}

    fig.append_trace({
        'x': data['time'],
        'y': data['Altitude'],
        'name': 'Altitude',
        'mode': 'lines+markers',
        'type': 'scatter'
    }, 1, 1)
    fig.append_trace({
        'x': data['Longitude'],
        'y': data['Latitude'],
        'text': data['time'],
        'name': 'Longitude vs Latitude',
        'mode': 'lines+markers',
        'type': 'scatter'
    }, 2, 1)

    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The difference is that, in my dashboard, there are about twenty different time series and every one of those time series gets updated every two seconds. Right now, my dashboard runs sequentially and without any parallelization, but it ends up being pretty slow both because there are a lot of time series to update and there is a lot of data.

I am on a windows machine and I set up waitress using this command: `waitress.serve(app.server, threads = 16)`

What do I need to change about my script to take advantage of parallelization? I was thinking about making a different callback for every time series and having them all update the figure independently of one another.

Comment: you can add multiple intervals and try pattern matching callback, to handle the callbacks. Not sure of the consequence on web page for using these callbacks.

Comment: What do you mean by pattern matching callbacks? This is a scenario I'm concerned about: callback A starts, callback B starts, callback A finishes. Now, when callback B finishes it won't have the updates from calback A

Comment: you can have multiple callbacks for multiple graphs

Comment: it is a single graph object with subplots

Comment: Similar problem. Callbacks in one session are blocking callbacks in another session. So, when one user executes a long callback, the app is blocked for other users.